# ng-change is not firing when changing value from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to reflect some changes to controller B (inside some event) when I make change at controller A. For that I am using a service.
When I am changing service value from FirstCtrl,  ng-change is not firing at SecondCtrl. Is there anything I have missed or need to change?

Please note that I am using angular 1.5.6. and don't want to use watch or even scope.
Below is my code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Data', function() {
  return {
    FirstName: ''
  };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', ['Data',
  function(Data) {
    var self = this;
    debugger
    self.changeM = function() {
      debugger
      Data.FirstName = self.FirstName;
    };

  }
]);

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', ['Data',
  function(Data) {
    var self = this;


    self.FirstName = Data;

    self.changeM = function() {
      alert(1);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl as c">
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.FirstName" data-ng-change="c.changeM()">
    <br>Input is : <strong>{{c.FirstName}}</strong>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as c1">
      Input should also be here: {{c1.FirstName}}
      <input type="text" ng-model="c1.FirstName" data-ng-change="c1.changeM()">
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>


</div>
```

Comment: I'm wondering what do you have against $scope or watch?

Answer (score 4):

As you dont want to use $scope trying modifying the code in order to use $emit and $on feature in angular js to communicate between two controllers. You can refer [this link](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Data', function() {
  return {
    FirstName: ''
  };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', ['Data',
  function(Data) {
    var self = this;
    debugger
    self.changeM = function() {
      debugger
      //Data.FirstName = self.FirstName;
      Data.$on('emitData',function(event,args){
        Data.FirstName=args.message
        document.write(Data.FirstName)
      })
    };

  }
]);

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', ['Data',
  function(Data) {
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = Data;
    self.changeM = function() {
       Data.$emit('emitData',{
        message:Data.FirstName
      })

    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Deepanjan, thank you for the answer. I am just wondering if I could use the same syntax with or without minimal changes with angular 2.X?

Comment: Hi! Please find the below fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/gz7j7ke7/ I am getting undefined error Data.$on and Data.$emit

Comment: Replace Data with $scope then only it will work. How can you expect this to work without $scope

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that I don't want to use $scope and your solution has Data.$emit and Data.$on... anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Okk give me some time i will have a look at it and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way then is to directly copy the reference of the data object within the controller. Note that you don't need ng-change to update the value then.

If you want something else, either wrap the `FirstName` in a sub object of Data and do the same i did :

```
Data = {foo:'FirstName'};
```

Or use $watch since it's the whole purpose of that function.

Here is a working code with copying the Data object in the controller.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Data', function() {
  return {
    FirstName: ''
  };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', ['Data',
  function(Data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Data=Data;
    debugger
    self.changeM = function() {
      debugger
     
    };

  }
]);

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', ['Data',
  function(Data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Data = Data;

    
    self.changeM = function() {
      alert(1);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl as c">
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.Data.FirstName" data-ng-change="c.changeM()">
    <br>Input is : <strong>{{c.Data.FirstName}}</strong>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as c1">
      Input should also be here: {{c1.Data.FirstName}}
      <input type="text" ng-model="c1.Data.FirstName" data-ng-change="c1.changeM()">
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to solve the problem is using watch, unfortunately. (I am new to angular.)

From the ngChange document (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

```
    The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

It will not be evaluated:

    if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has not changed
    if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null
    **if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value**
```

Comment: Oh my bad..Thank you for the documentation reference.